# How do I write a square bracket in a php function

Tags: php

I need to write a function to cut off a string at the "[" (square bracket).

This is what I got so far

```
function desc_sli( $slice= '' ) {
    $sliceVal = strtok( $slice, '[');
    return $sliceVal;
}
```

It doesn't work with the square bracket (with other letters and symbols it does)
I suspect there must be a different notation for '[' since the square bracket is also used in functions and arrays. Though I am not able to find it. Anyone who can help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your input string and desire output? pls explain.

Comment: Are you sure it's a `[` and not `%5B`? Works here https://3v4l.org/OP6t9

Comment: Dump the value of `$slice` inputted and returned.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Inputted and outputted strings are just pieces of text. With the brackets I want to select the relevant tekst from a website. The example from AbraCadaver is exactly what I want to establish. I now know that it is an error in the plugin, that I am trying to configure (WP All Export). I will contact the development team. Thanks again for your help.